# How lo create a intro like this?

Tags: logo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvFHyFW_jFc

I watched this video and wondering how to make a intro logo like this!
Which software I'd have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Program called: Adobe After Effect.

[And follow these tutorials](http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/)
Sometimes the dude in this website add the source file also, so you don't need to do the tutorial. Just edit the source file.

No need to mention that it requires some experience and patience.

Answer (score 0):

You will need One or Two Software to make that kind of effects. First is Adobe After Effects and Cinema 4D. If you don't want Cinema 4D, You can use After Effects And A plugin Called Element 3D.

Search "After Effects and Element 3D" For more details. Hope that solved.